# External DVD drive won't open

Tags: raspbmc

In anticipation of the MPEG2 hardware decode license being available, I bought an [external DVD drive](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=270727535686).

It works fine on my Windows 7 laptop. However, when I connect it to my raspberry pi, I'm unable to get the drive to open. All that happens is that the drive light flashes a couple of times and then there's a click inside like the lock has closed again. I suspect that there's a software issue blocking the opening, but I have tried to use both Raspbmc RC 4 and XBian 0.6.2

I am not powering the drive through the Pi.

Any ideas as to how to resolve this?

#### Edit

I used apt-get on Xbian to install "eject" and then managed to get the drive to eject using `eject /dev/dvd`. However, I now seem to be unable to mount the drive. Also, it would be nice if I could get the DVD drive to open by pressing the button.

#### Edit 2

Now that I have managed to insert a DVD, I rebooted and `eject /dev/dvd` no longer works because there IS no `/dev/dvd`. I'm afraid that I'm a little out of my depth here.

Relevant output from dmesg:

```
[    3.164519] usb 1-1.3: new high speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    3.294011] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=1040
[    3.315175] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.334846] usb 1-1.3: Product: ODD-DVD SD-C2732
[    3.350829] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Initio
[    3.370019] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 0000000000000000W
[    3.380724] scsi0 : usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
```

Comment: How are you powering it?

Comment: Powered directly from a kindle usb-wall adapter.

Comment: What is `dmesg` saying?

Comment: I think that I've pasted the relevant section of the output above.

Comment: Does `eject /dev/scsi0` work? What does `dmesg` say during a button press?

Comment: "eject /dev/scsi0" returns "eject: unable to find or open device for: `/dev/scsi0'".

Comment: During button press the dmesg output doesn't seem to change. I may have missed something, though, because I just grepped for "1-1.3"

Comment: No need to `grep` - just look at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that dmesg returned results sequentially. In that case, when I press the button, nothing new is added to the dmesg output.

Comment: Driver issue I'd say. What module gets loaded when you plug it in?

Comment: I don't know. How can I find out which module is loaded when I plug it in? Now that I've re-read the advert it says that it works on Windows and OSX but no mention of linux. The Initio website is down at the moment so I can't search to see if they've a linux driver.

Answer (score 2):

The comments indicate that you are powering "it" from a kindle usb-wall adapter.

If by "it", you mean the RPi and the drive is plugged straight into the RPi, then the drive won't work.

This is because the USB ports on the RPi are only capable of passing through 100mA to the device.

Your choices are to use a powered USB hub so the drive is powered by the hub, or to do a hardware mod to get 5V to the drive without needing to go via the RPi

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. No, I was referring to the drive as "it". The drive is powered directly by the wall adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you can open the drive - to mount it, do this:

1. in `/media` or `/mnt` or somewhere else create a directory, for example `dvd`
2. to create it in e.g. `/media` you need to act as root: `sudo mdir /media/dvd`
3. next, make it available to everybody, even you: `sudo chmod 777 /media/dvd` (you can restrict it more, once you get things working)
4. the DVD drive is usually `/dev/sr0` or if you have more drives it might be `/dev/sr1` etc. so now mount it: `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/dvd`

This worked nicely for me.

This is far as it goes for mounting the drive.

Navigate to `/media/dvd/` to see your files.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I hope that my edits meet with your agreement - if you really don't like them you may roll them back and edit your answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have `/dev/sr0` (or any `sr*`, `cd*`, or `dvd*` devices). I notice you mentioned scsi and dvd, you might be looking for the wrong files.